# Snakemake shell command should only take one file at a time, but it's trying to do multiple files at once

Tags: snakemake

First off, I'm sorry if I'm not explaining my problem clearly, English is not my native language.

I'm trying to make a snakemake rule that takes a fastq file and filters it with a program called Filtlong. I have multiple fastq files on which I want to run this rule and it should output a filtered file per fastq file but apparently it takes all of the fastq files as input for a single Filtlong command.

The fastq files are in separate directories and the snakemake rule should write the filtered files to separate directories aswell.

This is how my code looks right now:

```
from os import listdir

configfile: "config.yaml"

DATA = config["DATA"]
SAMPLES = listdir(config["RAW_DATA"])
RAW_DATA = config["RAW_DATA"]
FILT_DIR = config["FILTERED_DIR"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{FILT_DIR}/{sample}/{sample}_filtered.fastq.gz", FILT_DIR=FILT_DIR, sample=SAMPLES)

rule filter_reads:
    input:
        expand("{RAW_DATA}/{sample}/{sample}.fastq", sample=SAMPLES, RAW_DATA=RAW_DATA)
    output:
        "{FILT_DIR}/{sample}/{sample}_filtered.fastq.gz"
    shell:
        "filtlong --keep_percent 90 --target_bases 300000000 {input} | gzip > {output}"
```

And this is the config file:

```
DATA:
  all_samples

RAW_DATA:
  all_samples/raw_samples

FILTERED_DIR:
  all_samples/filtered_samples
```

The separate directories with the fastq files are in RAW_DATA and the directories with the filtered files should be in FILTERED_DIR,

When I try to run this, I get an error that looks something like this:

```
Error in rule filter_reads:
    jobid: 30
    output: all_samples/filtered_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode10/cell_18-07-19_barcode10_filtered.fastq.gz
    shell:
        filtlong --keep_percent 90 --target_bases 300000000 all_samples/raw_samples/cell3_barcode11/cell3_barcode11.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/barcode01/barcode01.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/barcode03/barcode03.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/barcode04/barcode04.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/barcode05/barcode05.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/barcode06/barcode06.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/barcode07/barcode07.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/barcode08/barcode08.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/barcode09/barcode09.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell3_barcode01/cell3_barcode01.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell3_barcode02/cell3_barcode02.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell3_barcode03/cell3_barcode03.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell3_barcode04/cell3_barcode04.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell3_barcode05/cell3_barcode05.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell3_barcode06/cell3_barcode06.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell3_barcode07/cell3_barcode07.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell3_barcode08/cell3_barcode08.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell3_barcode09/cell3_barcode09.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell3_barcode10/cell3_barcode10.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell3_barcode12/cell3_barcode12.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode01/cell_18-07-19_barcode01.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode02/cell_18-07-19_barcode02.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode03/cell_18-07-19_barcode03.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode04/cell_18-07-19_barcode04.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode05/cell_18-07-19_barcode05.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode06/cell_18-07-19_barcode06.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode07/cell_18-07-19_barcode07.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode08/cell_18-07-19_barcode08.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode09/cell_18-07-19_barcode09.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode10/cell_18-07-19_barcode10.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode11/cell_18-07-19_barcode11.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode12/cell_18-07-19_barcode12.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode13/cell_18-07-19_barcode13.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode14/cell_18-07-19_barcode14.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode15/cell_18-07-19_barcode15.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode16/cell_18-07-19_barcode16.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode17/cell_18-07-19_barcode17.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode18/cell_18-07-19_barcode18.fastq all_samples/raw_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode19/cell_18-07-19_barcode19.fastq | gzip > all_samples/filtered_samples/cell_18-07-19_barcode10/cell_18-07-19_barcode10_filtered.fastq.gz
        (exited with non-zero exit code)
```

As far as I can tell, the rule takes all of the fastq files as input for a single Filtlong command, but I don't quite understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `expand` function in your `input` section of the `filter_reads` rule. What you are doing now is requiring all your samples to be the input of each filtered file: that is what you can observe in your error message.

There is another complication that you introduce out of nothing: you mix both wildcards and variables. In your example the `{FILT_DIR}` is just a predefined value while the `{sample}` is a wildcard that Snakemake uses to match the rules. Try the following (pay special attention on single/double brackets and on the formatted string (the one that has the form `f""`)):

```
rule filter_reads:
    input:
        f"{RAW_DATA}/{{sample}}/{{sample}}.fastq"
    output:
        f"{FILT_DIR}/{{sample}}/{{sample}}_filtered.fastq.gz"
    shell:
        "filtlong --keep_percent 90 --target_bases 300000000 {input} | gzip > {output}"
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I didn't realize that the `expand` function was causing all my samples to be the input. I see that now.